# iOS : Disable Push Notifications drop down tray programatically

Tags: objective-c, drop-down-menu, push-notification

In my app design, I have a dropdown menu from the top as the user swipes down the top edge of the screen. This interferes with the Push notification tray. Is there any way to disable the default tray dropdown when my app is in the foreground?

Comment: I wish there were. I detest that feature (both as a programmer and as a user). But I don't believe it's possible.

Comment: If there truly is no way to disable it, file an enhancement request at bugreporter.apple.com and ask Apple to consider it for iOS 7.  The more developers who file requests, the more likely Apple is to include it.

Comment: I will wait for a day for someone to answer and then file a bug report. Its likely to be ignored though, given that the Push feature is synonymous to geting a call or an sms during the app. Regardless, I will put my point across :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, there is no public API for manipulating the behavior of the notification center or how to prevent it.

I think it is a design decision to keep a consistent user experience at the price of developer freedom.  I do not think it's not likely that an app will ever be able to block a notification's appearance, and only slightly less unlikely that an app would be able to prevent the notification center from appearing.

After all, it is what made iOS so successful. The consistency between the operating system and apps in general.